# flickering content between vue transitions

Tags: vuejs3, lottie

I'm trying to blend between different lottie animations with transitions and v-if-else state.

works, but the underlying content sometimes jumps up for a frame. The json file is definitely preloaded. but it probably takes a frame until the lottie file is played.

somehow I can't figure it out, even if I add a background image in the aspect ratio to the parent div with the bulging image, it flashes once.

How can I prevent the bottom content from jumping up? is there something like a dummy content.

```
<transition name="fadepage" mode="out-in" >
            
               <div v-if="state==1" key="x1" style="background-image: url( /img/yellow.webp);">
              
                   <dotlottie-player ref="lottie2" background="#ff00ff00" src=". /gepenst2.lottie" ></dotlottie-player>

             
               </div>
            
               <div v-else-if="state==2" key="x2" style="transition-delay: 0s; background-image: url(/img/yellow.webp);" >
               
                   <dotlottie-player ref="lottie3"  background="#ff00ff00" src=". /gepenst2.lottie" ></dotlottie-player>

                 
               </div>

               <div v-else-if="fragestate==3" key="x3" style="transition-delay: 0s; background-image: url(/img/yellow.webp);">

                   <dotlottie-player ref="lottie4" background="#ff00ff00" src=". /gepenst2.lottie" ></dotlottie-player>
              
                 
               </div>
            
             </transition>

<div>
content that jumps up!!!
</div>
```